# how to test Asp.Net frontend?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, testing, automated-tests

Does someone know a good way to automate the gui testing based on an Asp.Net frontend? (instead of always run the pages and test the inputs and outputs of a control by hand)
Are there any references or framework to support these tests?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Watir](http://watir.com/) is one solution.

> Watir, pronounced water, is an
>   open-source (BSD) library for
>   automating web browsers. It allows you
>   to write tests that are easy to read
>   and maintain. It is simple and
>   flexible.

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a Firefox add-on that records clicks, typing, and other actions to make a test, which you can play back in the browser.

Here are a couple of blogs that help you get started.

One by [peterkrantz](http://www.peterkrantz.com/2005/selenium-for-aspnet/) and one by [stevetrefethen](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/AutomatedTestingOfASPNETWebApplicationsUsingSelenium.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/03/behavior-driven-development-bdd-with-specflow-and-aspnet-mvc/) details setting up Watir for web automation, and SpecFlow to write your tests.

Specflow uses an english style language to describe those tests. Its a method that I have been looking at recently. I've found it very useful, the number of actions you can perform on the web are relatively small, and lend themselves well to this style of language (go here, type this, click that, check something etc).